# Bash script won't add @gmail.com to end of .csv input column

Tags: bash, csv

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3
do
    email="$col3"
    email+='@gmail.com'
    echo $email

done < ~/Desktop/Names.csv
```

I don't have to do anything special with Column 1 or 2, but adding @gmail.com to column 3 just outputs @gmail.com or if the input string is longer @gmail.com+longer bit of input string.

ie.

If column 3 was Dekkars, I get @gmail.com. If it is aaaaaaaaaaa (one length longer than @gmail.com) I get @gmail.coma

I'm sure this is something to do with the @ sign, but I've tried using \ to escape it, single quotes, etc. Any ideas?

I've already read concatenating bash strings, and I'm doing what it suggests with different outcomes than are expected.

Here is input Data

```
Test Name,8,aaaaaaaaaaa
John Doe,8,bbbbbbbbbbbb
Name,Grade,ID
```

(Note, I have columns at bottom because otherwise my while loop won't read the bottom row)

Output

```
@gmail.coma
@gmail.combb
```

Comment: Did you try `email="${col3}@gmail.com"` instead? In not sure about `+=` in bash... The `@` is protected by single quotes so it's not interpreted.

Comment: Still doing the same thing! This is driving me batty. Wondering if it isn't just easier having another column on the .csv with the email already there...

Comment: when you work on column-based data, consider giving awk a try.

Comment: Please provide at least one line of the input data, better two -- the code work as is in bash and zsh when typed into the shell.

Comment: Added input and output

Comment: I smell a problem with line endings. `$col3` might contain a CR (`\r`, `0x0D`) at the end; printing that and having it followed by `@gmail.com` writes `@gmail.com` to the start of the line.

Comment: @glglgl you're right, that's it.  I 'unix2dos'ed my example csv file and that produces the output Dekkars describes. @Dekkars: does `file ~/Desktop/Names.csv` say 'with CRLF line terminators'? Then `dos2unix ~/Desktop/Names.csv` and see if that helps.

Comment: `awk -F , '{ print $3 "@gmail.com" }' Names.csv` should be noticeably faster as well as fix the quoting error.

Answer (score 0):

dos2unix fixed the problem. Incorporated it into my script so I don't have to remember to call it every time I change the .csv...

Thank you all!